# Checking to see whether a hardcoded value is present in a gxt simplecombobox

Tags: java, extjs, combobox, gxt

I'm using gxt 2.0.3 in Java and I have created a SimpleComboBox which I then populate with 2 strings.

```
final SimpleComboBox<String> accessedComboBox = new SimpleComboBox<String>();
accessedComboBox.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
accessedComboBox.setEmptyText("Select a type");     
accessedComboBox.add("Method 1");
accessedComboBox.add("Method 2");
```

I also have a listener attached to a different SimpleComboBox and depending on what is selected I need to either add or remove the value from the above accessedComboBox

```
if (typeComboBox.getSimpleValue() == "Type 1")
{
    //Remove desktop app option
    accessedComboBox.remove("Method 2");
}
else
{
    if (accessedComboBox.??) { // <--- Check to see whether desktop app is an option
        //if not then add it
        accessedComboBox.add("Method 2");
    }       
}
```

I can't work out what function to use to check the see whether an option already exists in the SimpleComboBox. I have looked in [this documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.extjs/gxt/2.1.1/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/SimpleComboBox.java?av=f) but I've still had no luck.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you got this yet.  It's a little funky, but you can get the String values from the ListStore.  Something like this:

```
for (SimpleComboValue<String> value : accessedComboBox.getStore().getModels()) {
   if (!value.getValue().equals("Method 1")){
       accessedComboBox.add("Method 1");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I needed it to. I don't fully understand ListStores yet so thanks :)